# In NASM, is MOV EBX, AX a valid instruction?

Tags: nasm, cpu-registers

In NASM, is MOV EBX, AX a valid instruction?

Basically, can you move the contents of a small register into a register bigger than it?

Comment: What does nasm say when you try to assemble it?

Answer (score 2):

That's not valid anywhere. To get the effect you want, do

```
MOVZX EBX, AX, or
MOVSX EBX, AX
```

depending on whether you want to zero or sign extend the source operand.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not valid and what MOVZX mean?

Comment: I still don't understand why it's not valid to move a small register into a larger one. I can see why it might not be smart (since extra bits might be present already) but why is it not valid?

Comment: That was a decision that the Intel engineers made when they designed the instruction set. Since there is nothing in the value itself that defines whether it is signed or unsigned, the instruction must encode whether or not a sign bit needs to be extended when expanding to a wider value.